# jQuery - avoiding marking elements in web browser on double clicking them

Tags: jquery

When i double clicking some element in my web browser it mark it with blue marking. Is there possibility in jQuery to avoid this behavior?

Comment: I *hate* websites that prevent me from selecting content.

Comment: I hate too, but i need that only for two of my buttons. They will be clicked often and i don't want blue outline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
$("anySelector").bind("selectstart", function(){
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a blue outline, it is possible to remove that by explicitly stating

```
outline: 0
```

In the CSS.

This can form part of a CSS reset, which is to start your CSS with

```
* {
   outline: 0;
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: hmm.. i styled my element by `style="outline: 0"` but it didn't help.
For more i have: `<span style="cursor:hand; outline: 0">Activatee</span>` Is it good?